# Xcode version and iPhone app submission

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I am new to iPhone app development. I have an app created in XCode 3.1.3 and need to do 2 things;
1. Test it on my iPod touch (Latest OS: 4.1)
2. Submit it to the app store.

My question is, can I do both these things given that I have XCode 3.1.3 OR do I have to upgrade?
Also in case I need to upgrade, is it possible to download XCode separately (I mean without the huge 3GB SDK)

Comment: What iOS version are you using for developing? If you don't use the iOS 4.1 Framework then you will have problems submitting the app to the app store - I think it will not be possible to submit it, because you have to use the latest iOS Version.

Answer (score 3):

You must have the latest version to develop iOS 4.1 apps (as required by Apple for App Store submission.) As well, you must pay $99 per year for a developer account in order to gain access to on-device testing and to actually make submissions to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the whole XCode + SDK installer dmg to develop for iOS 4.1.  You can not download, or update them separately.  You can not submit to the App store using an SDK older than 3.0.  And you should use a recent XCode/SDK combo (as in the current 4.1 release) to submit to the App store.

Comment: I currently have MAC OS X 10.5.8...Will the latest iOS SDK work with this or do I need to update the OS X first? Also where can i get to download the latest OS X free?